# parse json from twitter data dump

Tags: python, json, twitter

I have received a dump of Twitter data which I would like to parse, preferably with Python (to start with).  I did not create the JSON and I am not familiar with the `StatusJSONImpl`,`UserJSONImpl` and `UserMentionEntityJSONImpl` directives.  How can I parse it?  Do I have to 'clean' it first or can `json` (or a similar module) figure it out?

Using `json.loads(s)` with the string below as `s` , I get `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

```
StatusJSONImpl {
    createdAt = Tue Sep 20 08: 31: 28 CST 2011,
    id = 115946140620435456,
    text = 'RT @williamsanches: 4? Dica: Sonhe sempre. Deus acredita no cora??o que sonha!',
    source = 'web',
    isTruncated = false,
    inReplyToStatusId = -1,
    inReplyToUserId = -1,
    isFavorited = false,
    inReplyToScreenName = 'null',
    geoLocation = null,
    place = null,
    retweetCount = 3,
    wasRetweetedByMe = false,
    contributors = null,
    annotations = null,
    retweetedStatus = StatusJSONImpl {
        createdAt = Tue Sep 20 08: 29: 50 CST 2011,
        id = 115945729465401344,
        text = '4? Dica: Sonhe sempre. Deus acredita no cora??o que sonha!',
        source = 'web',
        isTruncated = false,
        inReplyToStatusId = -1,
        inReplyToUserId = -1,
        isFavorited = false,
        inReplyToScreenName = 'null',
        geoLocation = null,
        place = null,
        retweetCount = 3,
        wasRetweetedByMe = false,
        contributors = null,
        annotations = null,
        retweetedStatus = null,
        userMentionEntities = [],
        urlEntities = [],
        hashtagEntities = [],
        user = UserJSONImpl {
            id = 54728012, name = 'William_Sanches', screenName = 'williamsanches', location = '', description = 'Professor Universitário, escritor e palestrante.', isContributorsEnabled = false, profileImageUrl = 'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1533016174/msn_normal.jpg', profileImageUrlHttps = 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1533016174/msn_normal.jpg', url = 'http://www.williamsanches.com.br', isProtected = false, followersCount = 10905, status = null, profileBackgroundColor = 'EDECE9', profileTextColor = '634047', profileLinkColor = '088253', profileSidebarFillColor = 'c7c7c7', profileSidebarBorderColor = 'D3D2CF', profileUseBackgroundImage = true, showAllInlineMedia = false, friendsCount = 232, createdAt = Wed Jul 08 07: 56: 17 CST 2009,
            favouritesCount = 1,
            utcOffset = -14400,
            timeZone = 'Santiago',
            profileBackgroundImageUrl = 'http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/125874404/tela-william-sanches.jpg',
            profileBackgroundImageUrlHttps = 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/125874404/tela-william-sanches.jpg',
            profileBackgroundTiled = false,
            lang = 'es',
            statusesCount = 7499,
            isGeoEnabled = false,
            isVerified = false,
            translator = false,
            listedCount = 130,
            isFollowRequestSent = false
        }
    },
    userMentionEntities = [UserMentionEntityJSONImpl {
        start = 3, end = 18, name = 'William_Sanches', screenName = 'williamsanches', id = 54728012}],
    urlEntities = [],
    hashtagEntities = [],
    user = UserJSONImpl {
        id = 170132028, name = 'Andrezza Santiago', screenName = 'andrezzasancar', location = '', description = 'Uma pessoa que ama a vida e vive pra ser amada.Ama acima de tudo a DEUS,sua familia e seus amigos! Alguém alegre e de bem com a vida.', isContributorsEnabled = false, profileImageUrl = 'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1505208968/DSC_0414_normal.JPG', profileImageUrlHttps = 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1505208968/DSC_0414_normal.JPG', url = 'null', isProtected = false, followersCount = 64, status = null, profileBackgroundColor = '642D8B', profileTextColor = '3D1957', profileLinkColor = 'FF0000', profileSidebarFillColor = '7AC3EE', profileSidebarBorderColor = '65B0DA', profileUseBackgroundImage = true, showAllInlineMedia = false, friendsCount = 330, createdAt = Sat Jul 24 09: 02: 05 CST 2010,
        favouritesCount = 0,
        utcOffset = -14400,
        timeZone = 'Santiago',
        profileBackgroundImageUrl = 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/321379737/images__2_.jpg',
        profileBackgroundImageUrlHttps = 'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/321379737/images__2_.jpg',
        profileBackgroundTiled = true,
        lang = 'pt',
        statusesCount = 3129,
        isGeoEnabled = true,
        isVerified = false,
        translator = false,
        listedCount = 20,
        isFollowRequestSent = false
    }
}​
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to clean it first.  `json` isn't going to be able to handle that.

Comment: This hardly looks like JSON at *all*...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a properly-formatted JSON object, this would do the trick:

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_object)
data.get('ids')
```

where 'json_object' is the JSON outputted by the Twitter API. 'data' is now a dictionary representation of json_object.